# Discord bot number of guilds in presence

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

is possible to make Python code that will display the number of servers the bot is a member of in presence status?
For example "watching: 1234 servers"
If someone invites the bot on the next server it will change.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [`Activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#activity) with type `watching`, and use [`change_presence`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence) to assign it to your bot:

```
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    await bot.change_presence(activity=Activity(name=f"{len(bot.guilds)} servers", 
                                                type=ActivityType.watching))

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any way how to do it for this code?
```
status = cycle(['Hello', 'Yo', 'discord.gg/cZ8GcPF', ', '!cmds'])


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("=======================================")
    print()
    print("Hello BlackRabbit#3981")
    print("client id :", client.user.id)
    print()
    game = discord.Game("")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)



@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
```

Comment: Are you starting your task? You should include a before_loop that waits until ready and then call `change_status.start()` before `client.run`

Comment: Um, I gonna let it like this (your code and any cycle) but is it possible to make it updated every day or an hour or just after some time?